# How to make a vaadin combobox overlay wider than container element?

Tags: vaadin-elements

I have a vaadin-combobox inside a slim grid cell/column, when I open the combobox the contents is restricted horizontally to the space in the cell and I can't see the values. Vertically it overlaps correctly. I have been searching for some CSS to make the overlay of values wider like you do with a normal HTML picklist but I couldn't find it.

Thanks for any pointers.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to set the width of the css class for v-filterselect-suggestmenu and the v-filterselect-suggestpopup

Comment: Thank you, Chris. That set me down the correct path and I have it working now but I have had to modify the vaadin-combo-box-overlay.html file (!).

Comment: I couldn't find the v-filterselect* class you indicate anywhere except in the documentation. I didn't know how to use them.

I looked at the CSS in the overlay and see no way of adapting that CSS as it does not set any "var", nor "apply" for what I need.

Comment: This is the change I made:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joebordes/ad383c495c87ea05ba1b8c3d95bca2eb

Comment: Do you know how I could avoid changing that file? In other words: how can I modify that CSS from outside the component?